# How to use boost::container::list<boost::container::string>

Tags: boost

I want to collect list of IP from a char* and store them in the list. How to use  boost::container::list IP.
Please help.

Comment: And do you get a char* per element that you want to add to the list or does the char* have some special formatting that you need to parse in some way? i.e. give example input and output.

Comment: The input is a collection of char* which store the ip address like "121.1.1.1" and it will be 20 ip's. And I want to parse this each IP and validate them.

Comment: Show what you have got already

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution using this example http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/examples.html